# if else statement to compare product amount and safetystock amount columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

i want to show the printed statement 'limit stock has been reached!', if productamount <= safetystock.  both productamount and safetystock are the columns in product table. 
is it the correct if statement for it?

```
Declare @P_Amount int, @SafetyStockamount int 
IF P_Amount <= SafetyStockamount 
Print 'limit stock has been reached!'
Go
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. You can't refer to the column of a table without a `from` clause.  Where is the `select`?   Which product?

Comment: Has poster missed the '@' in front of those params? Please show your complete code.

Comment: And are you sure you want to `print` the statement?

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL statement can be as follows
First read values from database table into parameters for the related product, then compare

```
DECLARE @ProductID int

Declare @P_Amount int, @SafetyStockamount int 

SELECT @P_Amount = P_Amount, @SafetyStockamount = SafetyStockamount
FROM products
WHERE ProductId = @ProductID

IF @P_Amount <= @SafetyStockamount 
    Print 'limit stock has been reached!'
Go
```